# Авторизация из ActiveDirectory пользователей с несколькими ролями

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

Есть локальный защищенный домен для работы внутри фирмы. Для работы извне админом создан ActiveDirectory с пользователями которые привязаны к сертификатам. При входе на сайт пользователь выбирает сертификат, авторизуется и получает доступ к ресурсам.

Возникла следующая проблема - если у одного пользователя две и больше роли, то после работы с одной ролью и смены на другую (выбирает сертификат для другой роли) сервер не сбрасывает данные сессии чтобы авторизовать пользователя под другой ролью. И при входе под другой ролью сервер не дает доступа к новым ресурсам пока пользователь не перезайдет в браузер и не очистить кеш и куки. Настройки IIS по словам админа практически не менялись.

Есть идеи что может мешать сбрасывать сессию? Мы не нашли где и как выставить время жизни сессии.

Comment: А это пробовали - [ASP_session_timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153581/how-do-you-change-session-timeout-in-iis-8-5) ?

Comment: @Daemon-5 да пробовали, но приходится ждать даже больше чем выставлено в настройке, например ставим минуту, ждем минуты 2-3. Думаем как сделать кнопку "Выход" чтобы принудительно завершать сессию но не можем найти информацию

Comment: Вот решение схожей проблемы [Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742978/asp-net-session-variables-not-being-abandoned-when-browser-window-is-closed). А метод Session.Abandon "убивает" сеанс?